# How to validate number range array in textbox in visual basic?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, loops

So basically in a form, you have 3 textboxes and each of them you can input a number, then you have a button that check if each of these textboxes are in a range of numbers specified. It's very much like a lock combo, but I need help checking values, for example;
[image]

the only thing i can figure out is

```
Dim intOne As Integer
    Dim intTwo As Integer
    Dim intThree As Integer
    Dim blnInputOk As Boolean = True

    If Integer.TryParse(lblOne.Text, intOne) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Value must be an integer")
        blnInputOk = False
    End If

    If Integer.TryParse(lblTwo.Text, intTwo) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Value must be an integer")
        blnInputOk = False
    End If

    If Integer.TryParse(lblThree.Text, intThree) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Value must be an integer")
        blnInputOk = False
    End If

    If intOne >= 6 And intOne <= 8 Then
        If intTwo >= 2 And intOne <= 9 Then
            If intThree >= 0 And intThree <= 8 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Good code!")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong, number must be between range 0 to 8")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong, number must be between range 2 to 9")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong, number must be between range 6 to 8")
    End If
```

So my question is how can you make this code simpler by adding an array for number range for each textbox? I also know there is a possibility of adding a loop, but i'm not sure how to structure it, can anyone help? thanks

Comment: As smead mentioned below, the **NumericUpDown()** control was made for this as you can specify Minimum() and Maximum() values.  The Value() will always be within that range and is guaranteed to be an Integer.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Actually, the NumericUpDown uses `Decimal` type (Min, Max, Value and Increment are all Decimal).  The `DecimalPlaces` property defaults to 0 so it is easy to think it is Integer, but it isnt.

Comment: @Plutonix, very true.  It is effectively an "integer" with the default settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, all depends on the number of values you are going to compare, the simplest is by adding a comparison function.

```
Private Function IsInRange(x As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim r As Boolean
    r = (x >= a And x <= b)
    If r Then
        MessageBox.Show("Good code!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Wrong, number {0} must be between range {1} to {2}", x, a, b))
    End If
    Return r
End Function
```

Then according to the code shown in your question, you can do this:

```
If IsInRange(intOne, 6, 8) Then
    If IsInRange(intTwo, 2, 9) Then
        IsInRange(intThree, 0, 8)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: woah, the second might help actually! the second code you've shown, is it an array? it would really help if I can store the range values in arrays, is it possible to show your code with the number ranges? (for example the first one, the lower bound number which would be 6 and the higher bound number is 8)

Answer (score 1):

.NET has input validation functionality on standard input controls. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z2h4sw.aspx) a decent place to start.

Comment: Also, for integers you may as well just use NumericUpDown.