# how to get number range in array element in visual basic?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

As the title says, I have created an array;

```
Dim intArray(6) As Integer
```

How can you calculate the range of an element? For example, using numbers, how do you find the range of intArray(3) if you want that element to be between a number range 2 to 5 and on array element intArray(5) to be between the range of 4 to 8? I just want to do this an easy way using loops and with stored arrays if possible, thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking about. Not even a thing...

Comment: Can you try again to explain exactly what you are trying to do, this is making little to no sense. an element of an array like you are showing as an example is a single item, it does not have a range, your array does.

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm not clear guys, I actually asked a question early before, but I got really confused with the answers I got, here is the link to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134383/how-to-validate-number-range-array-in-textbox-in-visual-basic

Answer (score 1):

Going by your other question and this one.  I would hazard a guess that a series of NumericUpDown controls to get your input would help.  You can set the minimum, maximum and interval of each one.  Now all your values are validated and in the ranges you want, ready to put into your array.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've miss read the question you want to calculate the range of the values in an array.

```
dim Range as integer

Range = intArray.max - intArray.min
```

Comment: Also the number of element of the array is: intArray.getlength(0)